# jQuery remove class 'is-active' from div on document click but also on click of the trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search icon trigger and on click I show a div, but I want to hide the div on click of anywhere else apart from the div and also if the div has class 'is-active' then on click of the trigger it should remove the 'is-active' class. I have the following code.

```
$('.search-icon').parent().on('click',function() {
if($('.search-box').is('.is-active')) {
  $('.search-box').removeClass('is-active');
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('.search-box');

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      container.removeClass('is-active');
    }
  });
}
else {
  $('.search-box').addClass('is-active');
}
});
```

The problem is even when I click on the trigger, it checks if the '.search-box' has a class '.is-active' and removes it but jumps to the else block instead of stopping the execution. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you make fiddle link ..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way

```
$('.web-icon-container > a > .search-icon').parent().on('click',function() {
$('.web-icon-container').find('.search-box').toggleClass('is-active');

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).is('.web-icon-container > a > .search-icon') &&
  $('.web-icon-container').find('.search-box').has(e.target).length === 0){
    if($('.web-icon-container').find('.search-box').hasClass('is-active')) {
      $('.web-icon-container').find('.search-box').removeClass('is-active');
    }
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to hide the div on click of anywhere and remove the class - Used  this code

> Used `toggleClass` to add class and remove class on click event

```
$('.search-icon').parent().on('click',function() {
    $('.search-box').toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

> You can apply `click` on `body` of document and cancel `click` processing if the `click` event is generated by div with class `search-box`, This will bind event to single element and saving binding of `click` with every element except `search-box`

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('.search-box, .search-box *')){
        if($( ".search-box" ).hasClass( "is-active" ))
        {
          $('.search-box').removeClass('is-active');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using this, if I click on the search box elements even then it removes class 'is-active'

Comment: @LionelDsilva add id or class name which you want to except in this conditions `if(!$(e.target).is('.search-box, .search-box *')){ `